# coredump_filter for all processes

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Is it possible to set /proc//coredump_filter for all processes in linux at boot time? /proc/self/coredump_filter will set for current shell and all processes run in the shell but not for all processes after boot. Is this something that can be patched in the kernel ( currently the value is set to 0x33)?

Comment: Probably better off asking on [Super User](http://superuser.com).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The corey details can be found in `man core`...

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html

The kernel param docs give us this

```
coredump_filter=
        [KNL] Change the default value for
        /proc/<pid>/coredump_filter.
        See also Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt.
```

If using grub edit your `/etc/default/grub` file and modify this variable.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
```

to this

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet coredump_filter=0x21"
```

then run `update-grub2` to update the boot config file. Note `0x21`. The bit params are

```
 bit 0  Dump anonymous private mappings.
 bit 1  Dump anonymous shared mappings.
 bit 2  Dump file-backed private mappings.
 bit 3  Dump file-backed shared mappings.
 bit 4 (since Linux 2.6.24)
        Dump ELF headers.
 bit 5 (since Linux 2.6.28)
        Dump private huge pages.
 bit 6 (since Linux 2.6.28)
        Dump shared huge pages.
 bit 7 (since Linux 4.4)
        Dump private DAX pages.
 bit 8 (since Linux 4.4)
        Dump shared DAX pages.
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see the definition of coredump_filter, you can change the behavior for all processes during boot time, just add coredump_filter=0x33 on kernel boot command line.

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/fork.c?v=2.6.35#L463

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use-case madvise() can be useful. Note that platform support widely varies for madvise().

Use MADV_DONTDUMP for the third argument.

```
madvise(void *addr, size_t length, MADV_DONTDUMP)
```

Comment: since Linux 3.4